# My code is stopping when I dont have blank cells in my workbook

Tags: excel, vba, blank-line

i am creating some vba code which automates the removal of merged cells and then deletes the blank rows that are created as a result of the demurging. The problem comes when a tab doesnt have any blank values. When a sheet doesn't have any blank values I get an error 9. Below is the code to detect and delete blank rows from my documents:

```
Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

should I try to include an if then statement to counteract this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually run time error 1004, sorry!

Comment: If you don't care about the error/situation, you can just disable error handling temporarily. Add `On Error Resume Next` before this line and `On Error GoTo 0` after.

Comment: `SpecialCells` is one of those functions that will throw an error and is generally best handled with error handling like @Bond recommends.  Depending on your data, you might be able to make use of `CountIf` to detect if there are any blank cells.  I would just handle the error unless it's critical to you to avoid error handling.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to go about handling the potential error of trying to delete something that doesn't exist.

First, you could check to see if there are blank cells.

```
with worksheets("Sheet1")
    with .range(.cells(1, 1), .cells(rows.count, 1).end(xlup))
        if cbool(application.countblank(.columns(1))) then
            .cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
        end if
    end with
end with

'earlier version of Excel may not have COUNTBLANK
with worksheets("Sheet1")
    with .range(.cells(1, 1), .cells(rows.count, 1).end(xlup))
        if application.counta(.columns(1)) < .rows.count then
            .cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
        end if
    end with
end with
```

The above has the disadvantage that the [COUNTBLANK function](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/countblank-function-c72134a2-695e-43ab-a3f3-714aa770f385) will count zero-length strings returned by formula as blanks while they are not considered trly blank by the .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) method. However, you probably wouldn't be looking for blanks in a column you know to be populated with formulas so this is a consideration, not a deal breaker.

Next we can test for *Nothing* by altering the error handling method.

```
dim delRng as range
with worksheets("Sheet1")
    with .range(.cells(1, 1), .cells(rows.count, 1).end(xlup))
        'temporarily suspend error handling
        on error resume next
        set delRng = .cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        on error goto 0
        if not delRng  is nothing then
            delRng.EntireRow.Delete
        end if
    end with
end with
```

Although widely accepted, I do not favor this method simply because I don't think you should have to break something in order to see if it exists but that is just my personal preference.

Comment: Thanks for the responses and feedback, I was able to solve the issue using:

Comment: the code: (On error resume next) before my line of code which deletes the blank rows